# Which statistical test to apply to calculate if a difference is significant between annotations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I have the following problem: I have a text which needs to be annotated with [named entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity). I have two annotators who have annotated the text twice. How can I calculate if the change in the number of annotations (first annotation round vs second annotation round) is statistically significant?
The concrete numbers are:

Annotator 1 (first round/second round):

- Person entity: 20 / 23
- Location entity: 102 / 108
- date entity: 93 /98

Annotator 2 (first round/ second round):

- Person entity: 23 / 17
- Location entity: 100 / 97
- date entity: 92 /93

Of main interest for me are the following questions:
I want to find out if there is a statistical difference between: 1) the number of annotations between first and second annotator (both rounds) 2) the number of annotations per entity of the first and second annotator per round

I already calculated other metrics such as [Cohen's kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa). But is it possible (feasible) to apply statistical tests taking into consideration that the number of possible combinations for named entity annotation can be very large?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the goals of this analysis? Are you interested only in changes between first and second round annotations within each annotator or are also wanting to analyze difference between annotator within rounds (akin to inter-rater reliability: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability)? If you're only interested in changes between rounds, is it necessary for you to break out the stats by annotator? Also, are you wanting to say something globally like there is/is not a significant difference in the number of annotations between rounds, or do you...(con't)

Comment: Are you actually interested in saying something specifically about changes within each entity type (e.g., person, location, date)?

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I want to find out if there is a statistical difference between:
1) the number of annotations between first and second annotator (both rounds)
2) the number of annotations per entity of the first and second annotator per round

Comment: It is better to incorporate the comment into the question.